# Just Audio Background Flutter: How to enable or disable the volume bar on the lock screen?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I have a flutter app which needs to play audio in the background. I was using just_audio and found Just Audio Background package - https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_background and implemented it for my app.

For iOS:
It works perfectly fine for my use case. The only issue is that on iOS, I see a volume control bar on my lock screen, which is disabled. I would like to either enable it or remove it altogether if possible. I looked at the package documentation but could not find and documentation to enable/disable controls on the lock screen. See image below.

[image: iOS volume control is disabled on lock screen]

For Android:
I am unable to see my app logo, next to the audio image. This works fine for iOS where I am able to see both the logo and audio image (see iOS image above) but for some reason doesn't work for Android. I am not sure how to load the logo in Android. See image below.

[image: Android lock screen does not show the logo, which is there for iOS]

Comment: Hey @sumita have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: i am facing same isse want remove it or add handler for it.